# Finding Substring from a String

Tags: java, string, substring

I have following String :

```
Test: Testid #123123 - Updated
```

I want to find the substring `123123` from this string.

I tried : `<msg>.substring(15, 21);` It gives me the correct result.

but I want to find this substring in the way that it should find the id between the # and the next space without giving the beginning and ending index.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
s.substring(s.indexOf("#")+1, s.indexOf(" ", s.indexOf("#")+1))
```

this gives you the string starting a the char after `#` until the next blank.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
String text = "Test: Testid #123123 - Updated";
int startIndex = text.indexOf('#'); //Finds the first occurrence of '#' 
int endIndex = text.indexOf(' ',startIndex); //Finds the first occurrence of space starting from position of # 
String subString = text.substring(startIndex+1, endIndex);
System.out.println(subString);
```

Or try to use regex

Answer (score 1):

If your example is really as simple as the one you give, then you will not need to use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). However, if your real input is more complex, then the regular expression will be less onerous than trying to split the string in a clever way.

```
import java.util.regex.*;


public class Foo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original =  "Test: Testid #123123 - Updated";
            Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile("#([0-9]*) ");
        Matcher matcher = mypattern.matcher(original);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just  split it with # then split the result with - you will get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex) ? You can search for the next space from the given index.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful..

```
String temp="Test: Testid #123123 - Updated";
 int _first=temp.indexOf("#");
 int _last= temp.indexOf(" ", _first);
String result=temp.substring(_first, _last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get the value between '#' and space.

```
String str = "Test: Testid #123123 - Updated";
str = str.substring(str.indexOf('#')+1, str.indexOf(' ', str.indexOf("#")+1)+1);
```